# Why onCheckedChanged() for RadioButton doesn't get raised in android?

Tags: java, android, onclick, radio-button, oncheckedchanged

I have a `Fragment`. There are two radio buttons in it. I am trying to create a `TextView` in 
this fragment and change its content according to the `RadioButton` user checks.
Below you can see my code. My problem is that when I click on radio buttons nothing happens/
Not the toast message nor the `setText()` seem to be called.
Please help me out.
Thanks before.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container,false);
    final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
    final TextView tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
    tv.setText("Testing...");
    l.addView(tv);
    RadioGroup radios = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radios);
    radios.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            tv.setText("changedText");
            l.addView(tv);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "zzzz", 2000).show(); 

            switch(checkedId) {
            case R.id.rbtn_sell:
                tv.setText("changedText");
                l.addView(tv);
                break;
            case R.id.rbtn_rent:
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(checkedId);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "zzzz" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return l;
}
```

Comment: RadioGroup you have at screen is not the same you are showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container,false);
  final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
```

the problem is here. You are inflating twice the same layout and returnin `l`, but attach the `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the RadioGroup you retrieve with `rootView`. It should be

```
 RadioGroup radios = (RadioGroup) l.findViewById(R.id.radios);
```

instead of

```
 RadioGroup radios = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radios);
```

Also inside `onCheckedChanged` you should remove `l.addView` otherwise you application wil crash because the `TextView` has already as parent `l`

Comment: Thanks a million man. Exactly what you said. I also got an exception before removing that l.addView().